# Can frissons provide an accurate metric to gauge emotional intelligence?

Tags: emotion, measurement, personality, brain, emotional-intelligence

This relates to my other post [Frissons on demand](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/20514/frissons-on-demand). As is stated in the abstract of the cited source below (which discusses voluntarily controlled piloerection), the ability **correlates** with personality traits of openness to new experiences, and **highly emotionally developed parts of the brain:**

"Compared to previously collected samples, participants reported significantly higher openness to experience, and absorption in response to aesthetic situations. These preliminary findings suggest that this rare and unusual physiological ability has strong emotional and personality correlates."

https://peerj.com/preprints/26594/

So my question is, can frissons provide an accurate metric to measure EQ (emotional intelligence)?